# Start Tomcat on Console from Jenkins

Tags: java, tomcat, batch-file, jenkins

I have a batch file which start Tomcat as follows (when running it on Windows it works fine)

```
...
start C:\Users\root\tomcat\tomcat2\bin\startup.bat
```

The batch file is called from Jenkins as follows
[image]

I have this error in the Jenkins Consol at the end of the build

```
D:\jenkins\workspace\Start 3T2>start C:\Users\root\tomcat\tomcat2\bin\startup.bat 
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I check the task manager I see that the server is started but in background. I need actually to start Tomcat it in the Console.

This is what I did :

- I added `-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true` in jenkins-slave.xml
  used to start jenkins slave service.
- I added set BUILD_ID=dontkillme in startup.bat to stop Jenkins from
  stopping the process in the end.

I think Tomcat start correctly in the end but not in Console. I'm running Windows 2012 server/Tomcat7/Jenkins 1.578.

Any idea on how to start Tomcat in a Console ?

Comment: Is this a `Master-Slave` setup or is it a standalone Jenkins?

Comment: Master on a Linux and Slave on Windows Server 2012

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Not yet. I didn't find an appropriate time to restart in production application. I would probably try it this evening and let you know

Comment: Oh...ok. Well, if it's production, then i agree, there are quite a lot of constraints. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, if you're trying to start Tomcat console on a given machine which has Jenkins configured as *service*, it will not work. To make it work, you will have to connect to the given machine using `JNLP`. In case it's a *standalone* system and you want to open a Tomcat console using Jenkins, you will have to set up a `Slave` on the same machine and that too using JNLP (`Launch slave agents via Java Web Start`) in the `Launch method` section in `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Slave Node's Configure` page.

You can connect to the slave using any of the methods shown below. You will see the below option as soon as you configure the slave node and click *Save*. I ran the highlighted command from the Win command prompt. In my set up, i had configured Master and Slave on the same machine. I have Win 7 Professional, 64-bit laptop.

[image]

Once you run the command, you will see a small window that will pop-up and will display 'Connected' message as shown below:

[image]

At least for me, i checked that `hudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true` & `BUILD_ID` parameters were not required. The only thing that i needed was to make sure that the following property is unset: `HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE`

[image]

P.S.: You might have to make sure to start JNLP on reboot. A start-up script will do that. Also, ensure that your project/job is *tied* to the given slave which is running using `JNLP` mechanism.

Comment: Ok that's works when the slave agent is started as JNLP as you described. Now, is there any way to avoid closing the slave agent window by mistake ?

Comment: There's a way. You can send the window to system tray. This will avoid accidental termination. For that, you will have to install a utility named `4t Tray Minimizer`. Google it. It is free. I tried it just now and it works.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to verify that this was the problem for me by creating a slave and trying to run again. However, I would prefer to run my jobs from master. Is there a way to change the `jenkins` user to no longer be a service, so that I can use it master?

Comment: Why is it that it can't be run if Jenkins is being used as a service?

Answer (score 0):

i was going crazy with this , as shutdown.sh worked from Window-Master-Jenkin-->Linux-Slave-Jenkins, but startup.sh was not happening on my linux-slave-jenkins though startup.sh execution showed success message, as there were no logs anywhere, it was difficult to troubleshoot, not sure how and why setting up "export HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE= " just before running startup.sh worked. Anyway Thanks a lot.