# ISO CopyHere powershell Process leaked file descriptors. Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am getting this error when I trigger a Job in JEnkins slave (Windows Server 2012)  to copy an ISO Image with a powershell script.

I have this function  "CopyHere (source,target)" on my powershell script which makes the copy Task. (And of course after that, I get this:

Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more Information)

When i googled it, i got a recommended solution, but the Workaround of Jenkins site is not clear to me... do I Need a Batch file to stop that, and what shall I write on it, and shall I put it on the Workspace of my Job.

Can anyone please clarify this?
Please I Need your help

Otmann

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you might not require what's suggested in the link you mentioned. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756743/start-tomcat-on-consol-from-jenkins/25871201#25871201) link.

Add this line just *before* the CopyHere command: `$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''`

I haven't use PowerShell. Just tried once to see how it looks like. :) Google told me that the above syntax is correct. You might be knowing it better. :) All you need to do is *unset* the variable `HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE`.

If my suggestion doesn't work, do let me know.

Comment: I wana know where to find "$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''", is it in sparate tomcat file ? or it must be added to the jenkins-slave.xml

Comment: From what i understand, you are using a script of which CopyHere function is a part. Put the above line in the same script. I hope this is the only script in that job. Can you please paste a snapshot? You might not have the privilege (due to less points) to attach a snapshot here so use some website which allows free upload of images and paste the link. Without the snapshot, it will just be a guess work.

Comment: here is the links of 2 snapshot--------------------------------image-1=> http://i61.tinypic.com/345gaza.png-------        image-2=> http://i61.tinypic.com/345gaza.png

Comment: Ok. Instead of setting `set HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=` just before calling the PowerShell script, try putting the command (that i suggested in my answer) _inside_ the PN_Watch4InstallPrinectS2.ps1 file.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, though  I put it in the first line of the script...I'm getting depressed of that. the amazing is, when I run the PN_Watch4InstallPrinectS2.ps1 locally it works fine

Comment: I hope you put this command: `$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''`

Comment: I even change the arguments of Jenkins-slave.xml with the following:-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true  without success

Comment: I will try to put it as you said...and I'll let you know how it is gone!!

Comment: it didn't work, I put it one time in the  script like you said :$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''  ,and the second time I put it im job...without success :(

Comment: Ok. Did you create this job as a free-style job or did you select some other option while job-creation?

Comment: I created the job as a normal free-style job

Comment: Ok, then i would request you to try setting this _inside_ your PowerShell script: `$env:BUILD_ID = 'dontKillMe'` and see how it goes. By the way, did you confirm whether `-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true` was _actually_ set on your slave machine? Please run `ps -ef | grep -i slave` and confirm once.

Comment: I made all the changes you said, here 3 snaps of the change I made:  http://i57.tinypic.com/106mvzr.png

Comment: And unfortunately with no success, I thinks Jenkins has problem copying a huge iso image, and doesn't want to wait till it is over, though we set it in background...if it's so, why comes the "precess leaked.." error message

Comment: For the second snapshot, the settings look fine but i asked you to check whether it has _actually_ been set. This can be confirmed by checking the output of `ps -ef | grep -i slave` on slave machine. Please paste the output in the section where you posted your question. In the last snapshot that you have attached, i see that you have put the `$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''` command before the PowerShell script. That is not what i said. I asked you to put the same command _inside_ your PowerShell script.

Comment: here my powershell script snapshot, where I put the "$env:BUILD_ID = 'dontKillMe' "

Comment: the command "ps -ef | grep -i slave" didn't work for me, I use it in the past in unix machine,I use instead "Get-process Jenkins-slave | format-list *"

Comment: Ok. So where is the output? Also, in the second-last post, you mentioned of a snapshot. Please put `$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''` too _inside_ the same PowerShell script.

Comment: here is the output of the command "get-processs Jenkins-slave | format-listm* " on this snapshot : http://i60.tinypic.com/2nuuowi.png

Comment: as I said before my powershell script:pn_watch4install, try to copy the iso image from network drive and copy it locally, and launch the installation

Comment: Jenkins copied the iso image, and then comes the "proceed leaked...", error, but when I copied manually the iso image, it takes 2min, but Jenkins made it fast, but I return he get problem to go ahead and make the installation

Comment: Your output (pasted as snapshot) doesn't say whether `hudson.util.ProcessTree.disable` has been set to true. I have not worked on PowerShell so i have no idea how to verify that through the same.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, then you can ignore the `Process leaked...` message. I remember someone mentioning in one of the thread that the issue got resolved but the error still used to come in the log. As long as the build is working fine, it's ok.

Comment: no the problem is not solved, because the auto installation is not launched by jenkins on the test machine, and when I try manually to install the isoimage what Jenkins did copy, it said :the file is corrupt

Comment: and I want that Jenkins give the right status and not the "Process leaked.." and if the file is corrupt that means Jenkins did not copy it well..and that's why the auto installation can not be triggered

Comment: Ok, from the comment you mentioned earlier, i thought it worked. Anyways, all i can say is that you have to make sure that the setting in your jenkins-salve.xml are actually getting set. Also, `$env:HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ''` and `$env:BUILD_ID = 'dontKillMe'` should be set _inside_ the PowerShell script, and _not before_ it. Once you confirm these settings are actually in _effect_, and if still things are not working, only then can someone suggest something to try.

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same error in Jenkins, though my "Pn_watch4Install.ps1" script copy the image, and launch the Installation, and when I give Jenkins a second Job (in the same job) to build, I get :

Comment: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Triggering a new build of AutoTest#4
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I mean this script do 3 things : 1-copy iso-imag,2-install it, 3- start autotest for this build. I 'm thinking of dividing that in 2 or 3 Jobs, to see if the known error still there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62401/discussion-on-answer-by-technext-iso-copyhere-powershell-process-leaked-file-des).